# Relative reference in INDEX not shifting after inserting a row

Tags: excel, insert, row, formula

I have a multi-row named range with formulas that do calculations on each row. When I insert a new row, the formulas should shift accordingly. When I do a simple case, it seems to work:

```
=SUM(INDEX(stuff,ROW(A3),0))
```

This code was in the second row of 'stuff' and, after inserting the new row, 'A2' changed to 'A3' like it should.

In my actual project, the formula is very long:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),"<>",S2UnitSelectorQ1,"<>2",S2CodeAssQ1,O$2)>0,O$2<>""),O$3*(SUMIFS(INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),"<>",S2CodeAssQ1,O$2,S2UnitSelectorQ1,"=1")+0.5*SUMIFS(INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),"<>",S2CodeAssQ1,O$2,S2UnitSelectorQ1,""))/(SUMIFS(S2OutOfAssQ1,INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),"<>",S2CodeAssQ1,O$2,S2UnitSelectorQ1,"=1")+0.5*SUMIFS(S2OutOfAssQ1,INDEX(S2ScoresAssQ1,ROW(A2),0),"<>",S2CodeAssQ1,O$2,S2UnitSelectorQ1,"")),"")
```

Here when I insert a row, 'A2' stays 'A2', and I have to re-paste the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the cell containing the formula and the referenced cell `Both` move with the insertion:

- If both move with the insertion, the reference is updated
- If only the formula cell moves down but the referenced cell stays where it was, the reference is not updated.

The logic behind is that the reference tracks the *same referenced cell* after the insertion is made.

Comment: I'm inserting an entire row. Both are moving with the insertion. It works when I do a simple test, but it doesn't work with my long formula.

Comment: Actually, what I'd really like to do is have Excel automatically fill in the formulas for the inserted row.

Comment: You can do that: select an entire row, copy (Ctrl+C) then insert.

Comment: Well, the spreadsheet is intended for non-technical users, so it has to be automated. I found that solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573689/excel-vba-to-run-macro-in-new-row-is-inserted. Anyway, that still doesn't solve my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why my original code doesn't work, but changing:

```
ROW(A2)
```

to this:

```
ROW()-4
```

did the trick.